# Where do I get Client Secret for Google Admin SDK?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

This documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_1_enable_the_admin_sdk_directory_api

Mentions that I need to have client secret, and the code sample lower on that page uses client secret.

However, when i go to APIs and auth/Credentials here https://console.developers.google.com/project/[proj]/apiui/credential#

I only can find clientId and private key instead.

Is there some other place I should get client secret from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wrong type of API, I need web API for that, but I used server API when I was setting up Authentication. Adding web API for authentication added client secret for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Google API Console is here](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

- APIs and Auth (left)
- Credentials Submenu

After I created an OAuth, my information was there.
(by my information was there, I mean successful showing of client secret, etc)